# In array or object add data with key dynamically

Tags: javascript

I want to add a object with key a data. but data is any string.

Example PHP

```
// PHP
$object;

// Knowing Key
$object["knowingKey"] = "knowingData";

// Dynamic Key
$dynamicKey = "key1";
$dynamicValue = "value";
$object[$dynamicKey] = $dynamicValue
```

But. How can i do this with JS.

```
 var obj = {};
 // Normally;
 obj.knowingData = 'Any Text';

 // How can i add dynamically data?
```

Comment: Did you consider picking up a book on JavaScript? This is basic.

Comment: Everything is basic for who is known. I use soo PHP. I didn't 
get used to JS. Any body may need this

Comment: You are expected to learn the language a bit first.

Comment: I think the point is that this is not a tutoring service.  The question is not horrible, and it's better written for SO than questions from many newcomers, but it's so basic that it doesn't really demonstrate any research.

Comment: The first few questions in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+add+key+dynamically, while they don't ask the same question, have answers that should guide you to your solution.

Comment: Ok . I will do it.Thank you. LightnessRacesinOrbit  and @ScottSauyet for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating data with obj[data]

```js
var x = 'anyText';

var obj = {};

obj[x] = 'any Value';

console.log(obj[x])
```